# ERROR: System table snapshots are not allowed in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I want to create snapshot for my meta table , just like other user tables.
But getting error :

```
hbase(main):003:0> snapshot 'hbase:meta','hbase_meta_snapshot'

ERROR: System table snapshots are not allowed
```

Is there any other ways to create backup of meta table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

backing up META is a bad idea, because once you'll restore it you'll end up with the layout of the tables not matching the layout described in META, causing the system to not work.

A snapshot of a table will already contains the META information for that particular table. And on restore the table will be created restoring its the correct META state.

so, you don't need (and it is semantically not correct) to take a backup of META.